# Do I have to do a dispatch again or why is my code not running?

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I am trying to make it so when I do an ajax request my preload shows up when a request finishes(success or not) it goes away.

I am using Axios and they have interceptors for request and response. I am trying to do request right now.

```
import axios from "axios";
import {setPreLoader}  from './PreLoaderActions.js';

export const axiosInstant = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:54690/api',
    timeout: 2000,
});

export const config = axiosInstant.interceptors.request.use( config => {
    // Do something before request is sent
    console.log('afaf');
    setPreLoader(true);
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
   // this.setPreLoader(false);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });


import {actions}  from './Actions.js';

export function setPreLoader(show) {
     return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: actions.SHOW_PRE_LOADER, payload: { showPreLoader: show }  });
    };
}
```

when my setPreloader(true) gets hit nothing happens. Nothing is dispatched. Not sure if I need to do something else as I only ever done this in a react component so redux/reactjs might be doing something for me behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

The `setPreLoader` function doesn't do anything itself beside returning another anonymous function. Therefore, just calling `setPreLoader(true)` does nothing because the anonymous function is not called.

You have to call the result of `setPreLoader(true)` with appropriate function:

```
setPreLoader(true)(someFunction)
```

Comment: Yea I just don't know what someFunction would be. When I call this in other places I have from redux "bindActionCreators" which does it all for me. But this code I have is not going to be in a component or anything so I don't have that redux "bindActionCreators"